# IPC: maintaining a list/map in shared memory in a Qt library on OS X

Tags: database, macos, qt, cocoa, ipc

Here's a nice little problem/exercise:

I'm working on a Qt library that needs to keep track of who's using a particular shared resource. If I were only to consider this in a single application, I'd use something like a registry consisting of a `QMap<resourceName, QMap<userName,QList<resourceInstance*> > >` that maps the list of instances to the named resource in use by a named user. The instance would probably simply be the `this` pointer in the instance constructor that would add a new entry to the registry (and ditto in the destructor).

However, the `users` here are applications, and there can be any number of those having (in theory) any number of instances to a single resource.

Which means:

1- My registry must be in some form of shared memory

2- That shared memory cannot easily be a file (or a property stored in the shared resource) as that would get corrupted too easily in case of crashes or other unclean exists

3- Using the instance address in the registry is likely to lead to aliasing when the OS maps concurrent applications to the same memory space.

This goes above and beyond what I've already dabbled in shared memory (namely only between threads, and not involving dynamic structures that can grow and shrink).

What's the best way to tackle this problem? In earlier implementations (fixed-size objects) I overloaded the new operator to allocate in shared memory, but I don't think that's a viable approach here - not when I hope to use Qt/STL classes. Qt's own SharedMemory class does not seem appropriate for dynamic objects either because I don't see a method to resize an existing shared segment ...

Is there a Cocoa IPC framework that I could use, and that exists from 10.6 onwards?

A file based alternative might be possible if OS X can open a file that has been unlinked (but is still open in at least 1 [other] application and thus not erased). That way, unclean exists cannot corrupt the registry. Supposing the OS can do this, I suppose that the "trick" would be to open the file in RW mode, lock it before reading, unlock it after (re)writing it, read its contents before any modification to the in-memory registry and then rewrite it immediately thereafter?

spoiler: the Qt library is KDE's kwallet framework, and the shared resources are KDE wallets stored in OS X keychain files. The underlying idea is to be able to re-implement the kwallet feature to close a wallet (keychain) when it is no longer in use (the current implementation requires a daemon process, uses DBus and just doesn't work well [yet] on OS X).

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but are you aware of QSaveFile, for 'safely writing to files'? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsavefile.html

Comment: No, I'm not (and if it's a Qt-5 specific class it won't do; I need something that's also available on Qt4)

Comment: What I think I will do is use QSharedMemory after all, and treat the shared memory block as if it were a file and using the in-memory variant only when I need it. A QMap can be serialised to and from a QByteArray via a QDataStream(QByteArray*,...) object.

Comment: That will also have the advantage that I can work out the protocol without IPC, and then simply add the IPC layer by wrapping the functions in an "IPC transport layer" ... (Get the registry from shared memory if it exists, modify it, resize the shared memory, write the registry, unlock the shared memory).

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Qt, I really don't get the yearning for platform-specific hacks. You can simply use named local sockets. They work wherever Qt works.

You can then decide on whether the data is stored in a distributed fashion by every instance of the library (presumably linked to the application that uses it), or by a central, single-instance service.

Comment: I'm not yearning for platform-specific approaches, they would just fit in nicely because the part of the library I'm working on *is* platform specific (hence the spoiler in my OP). And I'm a firm believer in not reinventing the wheel, so if Cocoa has 'goodies' that are tailored to my requirements, I don't see why I wouldn't use them.

I've thought about named pipes, but AFAIK that would still require a server process (which I'd like to avoid) ... and then I could just as well get the existing DBus mechanism to work.

Comment: @RJVB Named pipes can be used point-to-point between processes, no need for a central service. :)

Comment: The keyword here would be point-to-point, I guess. My use case requires something like a blackboard system, so either I have a daemon that maintains and serves the database in a point-to-point fashion to individual clients, or I have a shared memory objects that the clients maintain together (but not exactly at the same time :)) and that disappears when there are no more clients (which would be OK and probably ideal).

Comment: Starting to look into a hypothetical implementation I just discovered that QSharedMemory doesn't seem to allow to resize an existing segment. Bummer ...

Comment: @RJVB On a 64-bit system, resizing of the shared memory is pointless, just preallocate as much as you would ever reasonably need and you're set. On a 32-bit system, it's tradeoffs galore, but same applies: allocate as much as the rest of the application allows...